# Number of combinations to arrange the numbers into places.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let's say we have given numbers $N \text{ and } K$, and we have given set of numbers $A = \{1, 2, 3,\dots N\}$.
Also we have exactly $K$ places to put those numbers. What is the total number of ways to put those numbers into those places if it is allowed for each number to be in the set more than once. The order in the combinations doesn't matter.

**Example**

We have given $N = 2, K = 2, A = \{1, 2\}$ We have three ways to arrange those numbers. Those ways are $(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)$. Note that we don't count $(2, 1)$ because it is same as $(1, 2)$ and the order doesn't matter.

**What I started.**

Firstly, I was thinking that the answer is $N^K$, but it is not because on this way we are counting some combinations twice or more, so I got the idea that we should count only the combinations that have the elements sorted, where each element is bigger or equal to the one before it. I haven't studied for combinatorics still so I have only basic knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is $(2,1)$ not allowed in your example?

Comment: Because we are already counting $(1, 2)$ and $(1, 2) = (2, 1)$, or: we can say that the order doesn't matter.

Comment: But you didn't write that order doesn't matter in your original question...

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I will fix it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to see this problem this way: since you are sorting the numbers afterwards, you only need to find how many copies of each number you need to take. In your example you a) take $2$ copies of $1$ and $0$ copies of $2$; b) take $1$ copy of $1$ and $1$ copy of $2$; c) $0$ copies of $1$ and $2$ copies of $2$.

Therefore, the problem becomes just "how many ways is there to split the number $K$ into a sum of $N$ integer non-negative terms". This is a well-known problem, with answers on Math.SE or anywhere else on google. If don't find such an answer, ask in comments.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is the number of multisets of size $k$ out of a collection of $n$ items. If that's the case, the answer you are looking for is $${n+k-1\choose k}.$$

For more info, check out the [Wikipedia article on multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). It's a good place to start.